# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don´t know what's seems the problem to have this error. Anyone can give a little help?

---

```
protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string UserId;

            MembershipUser p = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

            UserId = p.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

            string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);

            string sql = "INSERT INTO [NOTICIA] (COD_EMPREGADO,TITULO,TIPO_CLIENTE,TIPO_ANIMAL,DATA_NOTICIA,DESCRICAO) VALUES (@cod_empregado,@titulo,@tipo_cliente,@tipo_animal,@data_noticia,@descricao) ";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            conn.Open();
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod_empregado", UserId));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@titulo", titulo.Text));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo_cliente", DropDownListCliente.SelectedItem));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo_animal", DropDownListAnimal.SelectedItem));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_noticia", DateTime.Now));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descricao", descricao.Text));

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            titulo.Text = "";
            descricao.Text = "";
            erros.Text = "Noticia publicada com sucesso";
        }
```

---

**ERROR:**

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native
>   type.

Comment: @GrantWinney i don't know... :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `DropDownListCliente.SelectedItem` and/or `DropDownListAnimal.SelectedItem`. You don't want to pass the whole item as the value but get the value out, like this:

```
        comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo_cliente", DropDownListCliente.SelectedItem.Value));
        comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo_animal", DropDownListAnimal.SelectedItem.Value));
```

Comment: But now i've this error:

"An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: the new error is obviously because one of your datafield in your database is integer and you are trying to pass a string to that field. it could be your userId or other fields on your database, if it's integer then you shouldn't convert your userId toString and if it's other fields match the data type values with your C# code.

Comment: @AliShahrokhi, agreed, with evaluation but not the "obviously" part. What is obvious to someone with a lot of experience often is not obvious to someone starting out or even changing technologies.